# Visual Basic web site in visual studio give a 404 error message

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have been working on a web site for almost a year using visual basic, bootstrap, and visual studio.  All of a sudden, when default.aspx is the active page and I click on the browser button to launch the browser to start executing the code in the default.aspx page, I get a 404 error message from IIS 8.0

How can I get a page not found error when I am looking at it?

Very Strange.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking why you aren't seeing a Custom 404 error page or why you're getting a 404

Comment: I am asking why am I getting a 404 error.

Comment: are you sure the Default.aspx page exists within the project and is the Startup page within the Startup project?

Comment: Yes, default.aspx exists within the project.  I went to project -> project properties -> web and verified that Specific Page is selected.  I even clicked on the ... and navigated to the default.aspx page and allowed visual studio to populate the text box.  But I still get a 404 error when launching the web application.

Comment: what's your URL when you see the 404

Comment: this is what I get on the 404 error page 
Detailed Error Information:
Requested URL
   http://localhost:18415/default 
Physical Path
   C:\Users\jonat\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AccuRecordBootstrap4\AccuRecordBootstrap4\default 
 

I noticed in the physical path, the file name that is specified is "default" not "default.aspx".  Might this be the root of my problem?  Why would the server think it should be loading a file called "default" as opposed to "default.aspx"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147416/discussion-between-jack-marchetti-and-jonathan-small).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understanding why this started all of a sudden but I found a way around it.  In the project properties, you can specify a specific page as the start up page.  Originally, I had local_machine/default.aspx specified.  I removed the /default.aspx and that seems to resolve my 404 error.  I guess somewhere, IIS knows that the default page to load is default.aspx if none is specified.  Thanks to all!